# Run Docker container with user who started it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

I have two users on host machine `usera`, `userb`. I have added these users to the Dockerfile as below.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    TERM=xterm
RUN groupadd -g 1111 groupname && \
    useradd -u 12345 -g 1111 -m -s /bin/bash usera && \
    useradd -u 23456 -g 1111 -m -s /bin/bash userb
RUN apt-get update ; \
    apt-get upgrade ; \
    apt-get install -y git ; \
    apt-get install -y vim ; \
    apt-get install -y curl ; \
    apt-get clean ;
USER usera
WORKDIR /home/usera
```

Based on last two lines, when I give `usera`, then default user in container is `usera`. If I change it to `userb`, then default user in container is `userb`.

Is there any option to default to user (and their respective directory) who started the container? If `usera` runs the container, then the default user in container should be `usera` and directory should be `/home/usera`. If `userb` starts the container, then `userb` should be default user and directory should be `/home/userb`.

Comment: As it's a run time request, you should use the `--user` arg to the `docker run` command (see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user))